# Splitting date in R

Tags: regex, r

I can imagine that this question is relative simple but I just cannot figure it out. I have the following string:

```
"2015-12-292016-01-28"
```

I would like to create the following:

```
"2015-12-29 2016-01-28"
```

I tried to apply strsplit with regex `(\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})` but unfortunately it does not work. The point is that I want to keep the dates in one string.

Thank you.

Comment: `paste0(substr(x, 1, 10), " ", substr(x, 11, 20))`

Comment: something like this perhaps: `strsplit(gsub("(.{10})", "\\1 ", vec)," ")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a non-word boundary `\B` and a capturing group with `sub`:

```
sub("\\B(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})", " \\1", s)
```

If there are more than 2 datetime values glued, replace `sub` with `gsub`.

See an [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/OZyVwG)

The pattern details:

- `\B` - a non-word boundary (only match a digit if a word character is before it)
- `(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})` - Group 1 (later backreferenced with `\1` in the replacement pattern) matchinf

  - `\d{4}` - 4 digits
  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `\d{2}-\d{2}`  - 2 digits, a hyphen and again 2 digits.

See the [regex demo at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/bW0vT7/1).

Comment: Thank you works, great! I didn't know the non-word boundary option

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. I think this is an ideal type of answer for those who still learn. Is there a guide where I can see all these regular expressions explained comprehensively?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `strsplit`

```
strsplit(v1, "(?<=\\d{2})(?=\\d{4})", perl=TRUE)[[1]]
#[1] "2015-12-29" "2016-01-28"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- "2015-12-292016-01-28"
```